# How to connect to saucelabs via Azure devops?

Tags: azure-devops, saucelabs

I need to test a connection to sauce labs from Azure devops but struggling to find the correct syntax for this?

Answer (score 0):

[This article](https://ultimateqa.com/tfs-vsts-and-azure-devops/#Sauce_Labs_with_Azure_DevOps) talks about Sauce Labs w/ Azure DevOps.

You will face issues setting and reading environment variables. Assuming that you are using C#, [this topic is covered there as well.](https://ultimateqa.com/tfs-vsts-and-azure-devops/#2_C_source_code_should_reference_environment_variables_like_this)
A [NodeJs](https://ultimateqa.com/tfs-vsts-and-azure-devops/#NodeJS_with_SauceLabs_and_Azure_DevOps) and a Java example is there as well.

One thing I will say confidently is that you definitely want to use a YML file to make Azure Devops connect to Sauce.

Another gotcha is the fact that the [Sauce plugin doesn't actually work](https://ultimateqa.com/tfs-vsts-and-azure-devops/#Limitations) and you can't use it to see videos. Hence, don't use it. Just configure the YML file as described in the linked resources.